# Does Google Play Store provide any mechanism for app activation

Tags: android, google-play

I need to be able to prevent the user from using my app until I allow him. The idea is that the app should be available for download but the user should only see activation screen when he launches it. 
Then he has to request an activation key through email and use that key to unlock the app.

Is there a way to achieve something like this in Play Store and is it allowed?

I also don't like this idea but its my client's wish..

Note to moderators: I posted a similar question for the Apple Store but I want to keep both threads separated so please don't consider this as spam.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google Play does not have such a feature out of the box.

I can however, think of 3 ways you can get it work. I am speaking strictly for the Android platform though.

You can design you app in such a way that the first screen should ask the user to get an Activation Code / Enter an Activation Code.

1. After the above, you can either store the Activation Code in a `Preference File` and check the value for its validity and start the application only if it matches / is valid.
2. Store the Activation Code in a *Database* and again, check the value and its validity and start the app if it matches / is valid.
3. Provide a couple of features and integrate [Google Play In-app Billing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html) and let the user pay a one-time fee to activate and enable all functions in the app.

These are the things I can think of at the top of my mind. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

**No, There's no way to achieve this.** You will have to create a functionality within your application.What you can do is make the user enter an activation key, if the activation key is correct make the user go to the next screen else don't let the user.

Answer (score 0):

Thats something you would have to implement in your app. If there is some payment involved in getting the registration key then the solution is clearly against the play store rules.

Answer (score 0):

i use similar system on my application. When user open the app first time. I ask for promotion code if this promoition code is true (i check it from back end service) user can use app for 3 months free. After this period end, app ask user to buy subsciription. You can do it using a backend service with interact a database.